# Local costmap is empty

Tags: navigation, simulation, costmap, move-base, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying something with the simulation of navigation with Turtlebot but with different frame_id's and topics. I checked that the laser data is being relayed to /scan and that my TF tree is consistent and that amcl and move_base are using the right frame_id's and subscribing to the right topics. Even with those conditions and with the laser detecting obstacles, my local costmap is empty (full of zeros) but the global costmap is just fine. Is there some other parameters I should consider that could influence the local costmap?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193925/local-costmap-is-empty/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2014-10-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally got it to work. While defining the obstacle_layer, my min and max obstacle height parameters were set between 0.25 and 0.35. Apparently the map walls in STDR are defined to be higher or lower than that. Setting the range between 0 and 2 was enough to fix the problem and my local costmap is working fine.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3